# NFA accepting binary strings mod 5

Tags: automata

Could you tell my if my solution is correct? I need to create a NFA which accepts binary strings (reading from right to left) if they are divisible by 5. My automata is below (green vertex is accepting one). Vertices are reminders mod 5. 0 is a starting vertex of course.

[image]

Comment: Why does state 1, have a transition to state 0 and to state 3 with input 1? Your automaton has many errors like this. For this type of problem a DFA would be easier to construct.

Comment: [see this answer of mine](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/97820/ugly-numbers-challenge/97847#97847) binary property of divisibility by 5 part

Comment: Your automaton is very strange, since the letter $0$ acts as the identity and the letter $1$ allows you to go from any state $q$ to any state different from $q$.

Comment: @john malick don't forget to accept one of the answers clicking the 'V' in the left side of the answer, and also to vote

Answer (score 2):

No it is not correcrt, the automata accepts $11_2=3_{10}$ and $3$ is not divisible by $5$